# Files missing during creation of custom TFS task

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Only task.json file created when "tfx build tasks create" command is executed, .js .ps1 and .png files missing. Are there any sample scripts to follow in order to create custom tfs build task.

Comment: Are you using the latest tfx version? I cannot reproduce this issue. "icon.png", "sample.js" and "sample.ps1" files are also generated after executing "tfx build tasks create" command.

Comment: I am using v0.3.30 version

Comment: There is known issue with the latest 0.3.30, see Cece's answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue with tfx-cli 0.3.30 (0.3.24 could create task without issue), here is already a same issue report on the website below:

https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/issues/151

As @bryanmacfarlane mentioned, he will update tfx in next step:

> Don't use that right now. Use this:
>   https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/stepbystep.md
>
> Since I finished the step by step, next step is to update tfx